# How do I repair a dresser with the side falling off?

Tags: furniture, wooden-furniture

My kids have a dresser and somehow they have managed to pull the sides partially off. (In all fairness, it could have simply been an age issue – the sides were originally stapled on and it is 20 years old). I've tried using a couple of screws to hold it together, but they aren't managing to hold it as tightly as I would like.

The design is pretty basic. There is an interior structure which allows drawers to move in, but the sides actually hold the channels for the drawers.

Comment: Some pictures might help, but it sounds like you just need to glue and clamp and then either staple or screw the sides back on.

Comment: Alternatively, go yard-saling - old dressers (even well-built ones) often go begging - a few bucks and the time to clean it throughly might be better than trying to repair staple-built stuff at the end of its life.

Comment: @John If no one has any better ideas, I'll give that a go. I can't image glue would be the answer, but why not?

Comment: Glue is what held it together when it left the factory...

Comment: A few photos would definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glue it & screw it. Staples were never a good idea & they eventually fail. You would remove the panels in order to hammer out all of the staples & to apply a bead of glue (wood glue). Then, pop a panel back on & screw (screw length should be twice the panel's thickness) wherever there was a staple. Repeat for the other panel. The screws are your clamps & the piece is actually better than new. Of course, wipe clean any glue that squeezes out.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing, but I had forgotten to come back after and update this post. Kudos to you because it worked.

Comment: Beautiful!!! I'm glad to find out you kept it & didn't just trash it. Great Job!